# How to automatically switch policies of roles (Terraform)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've created 2 roles using Terraform (Engineering.tf, Finance.tf)- 
Engineering with AdministratorAccess policy, and -Finance with Billing policy. 
I need to write a script to switch the roles policies every 10 min (endless loop)
I'm not sure how to do that when dealing with Terraform files

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to script running `terraform apply` on this schedule with different variables passed in on alternating runs. See [the documentation on input variables](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html) for more info. In particular, you may want to pass in a variable and switch which role policy is used based on that using [conditionals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals).